# Pandas and SQL equivalent (double grouping)

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I want to calculate count of days when the sum of the durations on that day was more than 30 minutes (per each ID)

```
id      date              duration
111     2020-01-01        00:42:23
111     2020-01-01        00:23:23
111     2020-01-02        00:37:22
222     2020-01-02        00:13:08
222     2020-01-03        01:52:11
....
999     2020-01-31        00:15:21
999     2020-01-31        00:52:12
```

This is my SQL for calculation this:

```
                    SELECT id, count(1)
                    FROM (
                        SELECT id
                        FROM statistic_prolonged
                        GROUP BY id, DAY(`date`)
                        HAVING SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date, date_end)) > 60 * 30
                    ) as t
                    GROUP BY id
```

And this is equivalent of Pandas:

```
df['duration'] = (df['date_end'] - df['date']).dt.seconds
total_activity = (
        df
        .groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D')])
        ['duration'].sum() > dt.timedelta(minutes=30).seconds
        .groupby('id')
        .sum()
        .astype(int)
)

print(len(total_activity))
```

But I get a different result on the same data. (Pandas returns more rows than SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note, and I’ve been effected by the same ‘quirk’ is that `.dt.seconds` doesn’t always give you the answer you’re looking for. A better option would be `.dt.total_seconds()`

Next for the grouping,

`df.groupby([‘date’])[‘duration’].sum() > 30*60 # 30 Minutes`

This will return an array of True/False, then you can simply sum the values:

`sum(df.groupby([‘date’])[‘duration’].sum() > 30*60)`

Comment: Yes! I I realized that False values fell into the amount too. I am filter them and everything became good. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help you out! Don’t forget if you are happy with the answer mark it as the accepted answer!